# Is it possible to COUNT if one value occured more than the other value in a column using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this table called task_status which has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `task_status` (
  `task_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `task_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_recorded` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `task_status`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`task_status_id`);

ALTER TABLE `task_status`
  MODIFY `task_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO `task_status` (`task_status_id`, `status_id`, `task_id`, `date_recorded`) VALUES
(1, 1, 16, 'Wednesday 6th of January 2021 09:20:35 AM'),
(2, 2, 17, 'Wednesday 6th of January 2021 09:20:35 AM'),
(3, 3, 18, 'Wednesday 6th of January 2021 09:20:36 AM');
```

and a status_list table that has the possible statuses available

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `statuses_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `status`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`statuses_id`);

ALTER TABLE `status`
  MODIFY `statuses_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO `status` (`statuses_id`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'Yes'),
(2, 'Inprogress'),
(3, 'No');
```

Now what I want to do is check which number occurred more inside the status_id column 1 occurred more, 2 occurred more or 3 occurred more? using SQL.

Is it possible to do and if so how to?

Comment: Do you mean `status_id` from [task_status] and `statuses_id` from [status]?

Comment: @T.Peter I mean the one from `status_id`

Comment: For next time, just provide the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` . It avoids the tedious distraction of all this `ALTER TABLE` stuff

Comment: @Strawberry Alright should I edit the question and get rid of the alter table stuff?

Comment: @Strawberry it is a column.

Comment: than what is the problem about simply count the number in `status_id`?

Comment: Well, I said 'for next time', but it's up to you

Comment: @T.Peter the thing is that I want to count that which value occurred more
! occured more in the column, or 2 or three did

Comment: @Strawberry Oki thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `count` the column first then filter with `max`
there is a lot of different way to do this but i prefer using cte.
Here is a example :

```
with cte as(
select status_id,count(*) cnt from task_status 
group by status_id
)
select * from cte
where cnt = (select max(cnt) from cte)
```

also here is [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2e8f90b3696a03fd17fcef5c3fae7e3) for better examine.
I modify some data to show the much more understandable output. But idea is same.

also I don't really think `status` table have any work doing here, but remind me if I misunderstand what you mean.

Comment: Awesome and well-explained answer thanks for the help, actuall the status table is joined with the task_status table in my php code but yea as for the question it was irrelavant sorry for that.

Comment: you are welcome, next time try to provide a clearer information which can lead to better and faster answer :D

Comment: Yes I will try my level best : )

Answer (score 1):

You can try OVER and PARTITION BY clauses, you simply specify the column you want to partition your aggregated results by.

Example code

```
select status_id,count(*) over (partition by status_id) as Count_1 from task_status
```

Comment: can you please format and explain your code a bit? but still thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can try the following code  `select status_id,count(*) over (partition by status_id) as Count_1 from task_status`

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly one status that occurs more often than the others, then I would recommend `group by` with `order by` and `limit`:

```
select status_id, count(*) as cnt
from task_status 
group by status_id
order by cnt desc
limit 1;
```

This always returns one row, so if there are ties for the most common, then you only get one of the ties.